# options_for_select selected value not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for projectuser data, but when I edit the projectuser, the selected projectuser stays empty, what is going wrong? This is the code:

```
= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@users.map{ |u| [u.full_name, u.id] }, selected: @projectuser.full_name), include_blank: true
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation states:

```
(...) 
options_for_select(container, selected = nil) public
(...)
(million examples)
```

So you shouldn't pass `selected: something`, but just `something`. Also, this something needs to be selected value, not text:

```
= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@users.pluck(:name, :id), @projectuser.id), include_blank: true
```

Comment: Does @projectuser exists in @users?

Comment: My bad, it should be: ``@projectuser.user.id``. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

following your answer I wrote something like this.

```
f.select :relationship, 
    options_for_select(
        Relationship.all.map{|rel| [rel.name, rel.id]},
        @order.relationship.id.to_s ),
    prompt: 'Please select', class: "form-control"
```

I get an Called id on `nil` error as this is trying to set a selected value which doesn't exist yet.
I'm on rails 3.13
my Order model has a `belongs_to` relationship with the Relationship model

Thanks for your help.