# unescape HTML in options for select

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I've got a select tag, which is used to change the filter via the URL. On change I reload the page to update the results accordingly. The newly selected filter should obviously appear as selected. But this fails to work.

```
<%= select_tag("filter_rating" , (:selected =>) options_for_select(rating_filter_options, (request.env['PATH_INFO']))) %>
```

I deleted the `(:selected =>)` as it seems [unnecessary.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373999/options-for-select-selected-value-not-working)

**rating_filter_options** value:

```
# [["by my rating", "/all"], ["1+", "/rating%3E=1"], ... , ["5", "/rating%3E=5"]]
```

The reason why the current filter will not get selected is that `request.env['PATH_INFO']` returns `/rating>=1`, which is different than `/rating%3E=5`. So the solution would be to unescape that nasty `%3E`.

I tried using `CGI.unescape`, `h`, `html_safe` on the `select tag`, but so far my attempts have failed.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I changed the helper that generated the `rating_filter_options` and placed the `CGI.unescape` correctly so it now returns:

```
# [["by my rating", "/all"], ["1+", "/rating>=1"], ... , ["5", "/rating>=5"]]
```

Also, I use `CGI.unescape` for the `request.env['PATH_INFO']` to make sure it is the same. The result in logs & HTML approve that it is correct now. **BUT** the selected filter still does not get selected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGI` should work.

```
irb(main):112:0> CGI.unescape("/rating%3E=1")
=> "/rating>=1"
```

Comment: `options_for_select(rating_filter_options, @selected = request.env['PATH_INFO'])`

Comment: Ok this is stupid: the `CGI` described in the **update** worked, but I changed a file in the trash without realising it... So the changes did not apply... Anywho, thanks for your help. ^^